# Uncrustify Objective-C space between open brace and variable arguments

Tags: objective-c, uncrustify

Just wondering if there's some uncrustify options to format the following:

```
- (void) fooTheBarsWithString: (NSString *) string, ...{
```

Like this:

```
- (void) fooTheBarsWithString: (NSString *) string, ... {
```

This just seems to be an issue with variable argument functions.  I would have thought the following would have covered it:

```
sp_fparen_brace=add
```

So this may just be a bug or limitation.

[Uncrustify Configuration](https://gist.github.com/spry-rproud/1cc0b21d6a6cbcc660d5)